# Fragment - Adding image in spinner

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-spinner

strings.xml

```
    <string-array name="meal_array">
        <item>Breakfast</item>
        <item>Lunch</item>
        <item>Dinner</item>
    </string-array>
```

dietary.xml

```
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/ddl_meal_type"
        android:layout_width="140dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:entries="@array/meal_array"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/lbl_meal_type"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.016"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lbl_meal_type"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/lbl_meal_type"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="24dp"
        tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="140dp" />
```

meal_layout.xml

```
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_action_food"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        />
```

Dietary.java

```
public class Dietary extends Fragment{
    View myView; //A view object called myView
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dietary, container, false);

        Spinner mySpinner = (Spinner)myView.findViewById(R.id.ddl_meal_type);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.meal_layout, R.id.txt, R.array.meal_array);
        mySpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        return myView;
    }
}
```

I want to add images beside the text in the spinner. The code in Dietary.java does not seems to work. I am doing it using fragment.
Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: use custom adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Dietary.java

```
public class Dietary extends Fragment{
    View myView; //A view object called myView
int img[] = {0,R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round, R.mipmap.ic_launcher_round};
    Spinner mySpinner;
    SpinnerAdapter spinnerAdapter;
    String[] mealArry = {"Select Meal","Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner"};

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dietary, container, false);

        mySpinner = (Spinner)myView.findViewById(R.id.ddl_meal_type);
        spinnerAdapter = new SpinnerAdapter(mealArry, img, Main2Activity.this);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
        return myView;
    }
}
```

Your meal_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:padding="10dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_weight=".8"
        android:padding="10dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Your dietary.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/ddl_meal_type"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now for Image with Text for spinner you need to make a custom adapter.
For this first create a new java file which will extends BaseAdapter, baseAdapter has 4 override methods.

1.)

```
@Override
    public int getCount() {
    }
```

2.)

```
@Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
    }
```

3.)

```
@Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
    }
```

4.)

```
@Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    }
```

So below is your SpinnerAdapter:

```
public class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    String[] mealPlan;
    int[] mealPlanImage;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    Context context;

    public SpinnerAdapter(String[] mealPlan, int[] mealPlanImage, Context context) {
        this.mealPlan = mealPlan;
        this.mealPlanImage = mealPlanImage;
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mealPlan.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return mealPlan[i];
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.meal_layout, null);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);
        TextView txt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt);

        img.setImageResource(mealPlanImage[i]);
        txt.setText(mealPlan[i]);

        return view;
    }
}
```

and finally your view will be like below image:

[image]

I hope you got your expected result.

Comment: Glad to help...please accept this answer, if this really helped you..and can help others...

Comment: what if i need more items in the spinner? Is there other way other than String[] mealArry = {"Select Meal","Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner"};?

Comment: @RichelleChia you can add more in this string array like String[] mealArry = {"Select Meal","Breakfast", "Lunch", "Dinner", "Snacks","Your choice"};
and accordingly, you have to add images in imageArray.

Comment: @RichelleChia or else you can also create an ArrayList<String> and then add required items by this line your_array_list_object.add("Lunch");,your_array_list_object.add("Dinner");

But then you have change String[] to ArrayList<String> in custom adapter also.